# Calculating time difference for fixed hour

Tags: php, datetime

I want to calculate the time difference from now (lets say 18:30:00) till this evening at 20pm.

```
$today = date('Y-m-d', time());
$remain = strtotime($today. " 00:00:00 + 20 hours") - time();
$remain = date('H:i:s', $remain);
```

I get a result which is one hour larger (02:30:00) than the actual result (01:30:00). I tried setting time zones but it's always the same result.

Comment: Consider using the datetime objects.

Comment: Use a library like https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon and make life easier.

Comment: `$remain` is initially the number of seconds between the two timestamps. It is not a timestamp. So, your timezone will alter it when you treat it as a timestamp. Just consider it a number of seconds. Divide by 60 to get minutes. Divide by 60 to get hours.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the `DateTime` object, you can do this easily:

```
$d1 = new DateTime('2015-04-23 18:30');
$d2 = new DateTime('2015-04-23 20:00');
$interval = $d2->diff($d1);
echo $interval->format('%H:%i hours');
```

Comment: Very interesting. If i follow kainaws suggestion i get a correct result which is just a few minutes off. This method gives me the exact result.